# Check value in hidden field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a value as an html text which is in a variable in jquery:

```
var data = "<table width='100%'><tr><td class='messageclass'><strong>Sam </strong>hi<td><td style='color:Gray;' width='85px'><small>20120507<small></td></table><input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='4,5,6,7'>"
```

I have a value with me it may be `4,5,6,7,8,9,10`.... any one of these

I want to check that whether my value is there in `<input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='4,5,6,7'>` in the value field.

Check my fiddle : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/a4pc8fn6/)

Comment: After reading the other questions, I am not sure what you actualy want. Do you have an Array or just the value string?? I mean your title just says what I answered.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay I have the value in that data variable as you can see and I want to extract the value from data variable and need to compare with my value thats it!!

Comment: Hi Santhucool - use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = "<table width='100%'><tr><td class='messageclass'><strong>Sam </strong>hi<td><td style='color:Gray;' width='85px'><small>20120507<small></td></table><input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='4,5,6,7'>";

var myVar = "5",
    hiddenIds = $('<div/>').html(data).find('#hiddenid').val().split(',');

if ($.inArray(myVar, hiddenIds) !== -1) {
    console.log('myVar is in array');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kscvzqz6/1/)

Comment: that html is inside variable in javascript its not pure html. your method wont work. Because `$('#hiddenid').val()` will return `undefined`.

Comment: check fiddle. You have to take value with respect to `data` variable. Other methods wont. work because its not html

Comment: Hi @IonicăBizău, there are many romanian programmers around here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `php.js` to use the PHP functions in JavaScript.

```
function in_array(needle, haystack, argStrict) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: vlado houba
  // improved by: Jonas Sciangula Street (Joni2Back)
  //    input by: Billy
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //   example 1: in_array('van', ['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld']);
  //   returns 1: true
  //   example 2: in_array('vlado', {0: 'Kevin', vlado: 'van', 1: 'Zonneveld'});
  //   returns 2: false
  //   example 3: in_array(1, ['1', '2', '3']);
  //   example 3: in_array(1, ['1', '2', '3'], false);
  //   returns 3: true
  //   returns 3: true
  //   example 4: in_array(1, ['1', '2', '3'], true);
  //   returns 4: false

  var key = '',
    strict = !! argStrict;

  //we prevent the double check (strict && arr[key] === ndl) || (!strict && arr[key] == ndl)
  //in just one for, in order to improve the performance 
  //deciding wich type of comparation will do before walk array
  if (strict) {
    for (key in haystack) {
      if (haystack[key] === needle) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (key in haystack) {
      if (haystack[key] == needle) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Using the `in_array`, we can use if you have all the values by taking `.split()` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert javascript variable into dom node to get access the element inside that. Try below js to get the values inside hidden field.

```
 var HTMLSTRING = "<table width='100%'><tr><td class='messageclass'><strong>Sam </strong>hi<td><td style='color:Gray;' width='85px'><small>20120507<small></td></table><input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='4,5,6,7'>";


$.each($.parseHTML(HTMLSTRING), function( index, value ) {
    if(value.id=="hiddenid")
        alert(value.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var data = "<table width='100%'><tr><td class='messageclass'><strong>Sam</strong>hi<td><td style='color:Gray;' width='85px'><small>20120507<small></td></table><input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='4,5,6,7'>";
    
    var $elem = $('<div>').html(data)
    alert($elem.find('#hiddenid').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

Okey after I got what you want, here is the solution:

Because the elements are not in the DOM, you have to use a RegEx for this.

```
var data = "<table width='100%'><tr><td class='messageclass'><strong>Sam</strong>hi<td><td style='color:Gray;' width='85px'><small>20120507<small></td></table><input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='4,5,6,7'>";

var hidden_value = data.match(/<input type='hidden' id='hiddenid' value='(.*)'/);
alert(hidden_value[1]);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4pc8fn6/2/

**Old Content, before the Fiddle existet**

I understood that you want to get the `value` of the hidden input field.

This is easily done with:

**Javascript (Vanilla)**

```
var hidden_value = document.getElementById('hiddenid').value;
console.log(hidden_value);
```

**jQuery**

```
var hidden_value = $('#hiddenid').val();
console.log(hidden_value);
```

Be sure that you actualy do an output of the `data`-variable (also do it before trying to read the value) or the input element won't exist in the DOM.